# HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> get value

Tags: android, hashmap

I am making Laundry app. User select items like this.

[image]

And i have a three TabBar for (Dry , Wash , Wash and Iron).
And i store the user selected item store in the three different `HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>`

My value store in hashmap like this.

```
Key:Name, Value:[Quantity, Default-Price, Qty-Total, position]
    Key: Trouser, Value: [2, 8, 16, 3]
    Key: Shirt, Value: [3, 15, 45, 0]
    Key: Coat, Value: [2, 7, 14, 2]
    Key: Pants, Value: [3, 10, 30, 1]
```

I want sum of all third element (16,45,14,30) in three different HashMap.
For Grand total of all items.

Comment: What have you done so far? Do you have a sample code?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Get the max of each list?  Get the third value of each list?  Something else?

Comment: See my old post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35199498/dynamic-listview-with-button-click-get-grand-total

Comment: i wanna to show grand total

Comment: @ArpitPatel What are 16, 45, 14, 30? Third elements in the `ArrayList` or max Value in the `ArrayList`?

Comment: third element of the ArrayList bro

Comment: @ArpitPatel You have a lot of answers pick one. :)

Comment: i just want to sum of all third element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `map` is your `HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>` then iterate the map and get the third value from the `ArrayList` and sum it.Try this,

```
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
    int sum = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Integer>> item : map.entrySet()) {
        sum += item.getValue().get(2);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Find full code here.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer granddTotal = 0;
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(2);
    list.add(8);
    list.add(16);
    list.add(3);
    map.put("Trouser", list);

    list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(3);
    list.add(15);
    list.add(45);
    list.add(0);
    map.put("Shirt", list);

    list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(2);
    list.add(7);
    list.add(14);
    list.add(2);
    map.put("Coat", list);

    list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(3);
    list.add(10);
    list.add(30);
    list.add(1);
    map.put("Pant", list);


    for(ArrayList<Integer> listData : map.values()) {
        granddTotal = granddTotal + listData.get(2);
    }
    System.out.println(granddTotal);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();
        // create list one and store values
        List<Integer> valSetOne = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        valSetOne.add(5);
        valSetOne.add(8);
        // create list two and store values
        List<Integer> valSetTwo = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        valSetTwo.add(11;
        valSetTwo.add(15);
        // create list three and store values
        List<Integer> valSetThree = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        valSetThree.add(6);
        valSetThree.add(55);
        // put values into map
        map.put(1, valSetOne);
        map.put(2, valSetTwo);
        map.put(3, valSetThree);
        // iterate and display values
        System.out.println("Fetching Keys and corresponding [Multiple] Values n");
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<Integer>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            Integer key = entry.getKey();
            List<Integer> values = entry.getValue();
            System.out.println("Key = " + key);
            System.out.println("Values = " + values + "n");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

How hard it is to sum up the 3rd index of an array and then store it in a variable.

Let's say this is your hashMap

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> clothes = new HashMap<>(String,ArrayList<Integer>);
```

with these values..

```
Key: Trouser, Value: [2, 8, 16, 3]
Key: Shirt, Value: [3, 15, 45, 0]
Key: Coat, Value: [2, 7, 14, 2]
Key: Pants, Value: [3, 10, 30, 1]

int grandTol = 0;
for (Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>> cloth : clothes.entrySet()) {
    grandTol += entry.getValue().get(2);

}
```

Just loop through the hashMap and add up the values.

Comment: *entry* cannot be resolved

Comment: check now. i have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    int sum = map.values().stream().mapToInt(v -> v.get(2)).sum();
```